# intuition for $\left|\int_\gamma f\right| \leq L_\gamma\sup\{|f(\gamma(t))|:t\in[a,b]\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis I learned that if we define $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be a continuous function and let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a smooth curve, Then:

$$\left|\int_\gamma f\right| \leq \int_\gamma |f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)| dt \leq L_\gamma\sup\{|f(\gamma(t))|:t\in[a,b]\}$$

Where $L_\gamma$ is the length of $\gamma$.

I think that it's easy to understand the first inequality $\left|\int_\gamma f\right| \leq \int_\gamma |f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)| dt$, it's just the triangle inequality I think, But what is the intuition behind:

$$\left|\int_\gamma f\right| \leq L_\gamma\sup\{|f(\gamma(t))|:t\in[a,b]\}?$$

Comment: The second inequality follows from $L_{\gamma}=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt$ and $|f(\gamma(t)|\le\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(\gamma(t)|$ for all $t\in[a,b]$.